# How old exactly was Rachel during the witch hunt in Manson?

Tags: comics, rachel-rising, terry-moore

When the readers learn the true version of the event from James, he says Rachel was but a child (15? 12?) during those events.

But Rachel is very old. Her "reboot" mechanism has her come back to life with an amnesia (almost) every time she dies. Does it also make her come back in a younger body? How else can it be explained that Rachel (presumably having lived initially to the same visible age as Lilith) was a child during the witch hunt?